# Looping through all named ranges in excel VBA in current active sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking to loop through all named ranges found in a `activeworksheet` and then do something to them. I've used the code below but it does not seem to produce anything. Also, it will be good if I can loop through named ranges that contain certain words. For example, my named ranges are named data1, data2, data3 and so on. I would only like to work on them if they contain the word data.

```
For Each nm In Activesheets.Names
    MsgBox "nm.name"
Next nm
```

Comment: Try just `msgbox nm.Name`.  The message box, as you have it, is literally showing "nm.name", yeah?

Comment: You may want 'ActiveSheet' and not 'ActiveSheets' as well.

Comment: You need to use `ActiveWorkbook.Names` and drop the quotes as others have said

Comment: I tried 'Activesheet' and remove the quotes. they don't work. and also there are other named ranges which I don't want to touch as well. hence the need to use the current sheet and not the whole workbook

Comment: Please see my edit - I think it will answer your question.

Comment: your edit gives an error of run-time error '1004'

Comment: @user7729135 I tested it without issue and included a demo gif in my post. What version of excel are you using? Are you putting the code into a module? Let me know if there's anything I can do to help

Comment: @user1274820 i tried to copy and post that whole thing in. it still gives me the error. i am using excel 2016 on windows. tried on mac as well

Comment: @user7729135 can u open a blank workbook, paste the code in, and run it - confirm that it works without the other code? I imagine you have something else messing it up - I can't get it to give me a `1004` error using option explicit (which would mean you need `Dim nm`) or anything else. Can you post any code that is running alongside it?

Answer (score 16):

If you only want to get names from the active worksheet, use this:

```
Sub Test()
For Each nm In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    If nm.RefersToRange.Parent.Name = ActiveSheet.Name Then MsgBox nm.Name
Next nm
End Sub
```

^ This code will only return named ranges that refer to ranges on the active worksheet.

`nm.RefersToRange.Parent` will return the worksheet associated with the range.

We can then retrieve its name using `.Name` and compare it to the ActiveWorksheet name.

Here you can see I have 2 Named Ranges on `Sheet4` and 1 on `Sheet3`

When I run this code, it only returns `MyName1` and `MyName2` - it does not include `MyName3` as it is not on the active sheet.

[image: Ranges]

This macro will only return the ones on my `ActiveSheet` (`Sheet4`)

[image: Names]

Comment: If you have auto filters on, you might want to add something like `And Right(nm.name, 15) <> "_FilterDatabase"` to your `If` clause, because it seems Excel defines the filtered columns this way. (What would be a better way of discerning between names you defined and potentially other things like these that might be used "behind the scenes"?)

Answer (score 7):

This macro will loop through all named ranges in your workbook.  It takes the comments above into consideration and shows how you can do things with specific ranges.

```
Sub nameLoop()
Dim nm
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
For Each nm In wb.Names
    If InStr(1, nm.Name, "data") Then
        ' Do stuff with the named range.
        Debug.Print nm.Name
    End If
Next nm
End Sub
```

Note, using `InStr()` will find "data" *anywhere* in the name. So if you have `data1`, `datas1`, and `myData1`, it'll run the "do stuff here" code for all of those.  If you just want ranges *starting* with `data`, then change the `InStr()` line to: `If Left(nm.Name,4) = "data" Then`

Edit: You can couple this with the `If nm.RefersToRange.Parent.Name = ActiveSheet.Name`  line suggested by @user1274820 below.  (Just make the `If` statement include an `And` operator).

Answer (score 0):

Just a little addition to Ben Philipp's comment: `_FilterDatabase` names have their `.Visible` property set to `False`.

If OP haven't added invisible names via VBA before, they could just check the `.Visible` property instead of comparing strings.